# Неизменность размеров Основного Окна PyQt5

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, pyside6

Как внутри класса основного окна `PyQt5` сделать это окно - НЕИЗМЕННЫМ по размерам?

---

**Update:**

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class MainWindow(QWidget): 
    def int__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setFixedSize(500, 200)        # ((1) ЭТО - НЕ РАБОТАЕТ !!!) 

        
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    w = MainWindow() 
    w.setWindowTitle('** Title **') # 
#    w.setFixedSize(500, 200)              # ((2) СНАРУЖИ! - РАБОТАЕТ !!!) 
    w.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно.

> QtWidgets.QWidget.[**setFixedSize**](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QWidget.html?highlight=setfixedsize#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.setFixedSize)(`w`, `h`)
>
> Устанавливает ширину виджета в `w` и высоту в `h`.

---

**Update**:

[**flags Qt::WindowFlags**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WindowType-enum) используется для указания различных свойств оконной системы для виджета. 
Они довольно необычны, но необходимы в нескольких случаях.
Некоторые из этих флагов зависят от того, поддерживает ли их основной
оконный менеджер.
...

Существует также ряд флагов, которые можно использовать для настройки
внешнего вида **`окон верхнего уровня`**. 
Они не влияют на другие окна:

> Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
>
> Дает окну тонкую диалоговую границу в Windows. 
> Этот стиль традиционно используется для диалогов фиксированного размера.

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
          
        self.setWindowFlags(
            Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | 
            Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
        )
        self.setFixedSize(500, 200)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(
            QLabel('Попробуйте изменить размеры окна.'), 
            alignment = Qt.AlignCenter
        )
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Bahnschrift Light", 18))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("** Title ** setFixedSize(500, 200) ")
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Qt.png"))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @staut Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо ребята!
Я в общем-то получил ответ на свой вопрос (как устанавливать и переустанавливать ФИКСИРОВАННЫЕ размеры Основного Окна приложения).
Извините, я еще очень плохо ориентируюсь на сайте и даже
не знаю как отметить Ваш ответ, как Правильный.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        # (изменение - ФИКСИРОВАННОГО Размера Основного Окна Приложения)
        self.set_fixed_main_window_sizes(500, 200)

        # (.....)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(
            QLabel('Попробуйте изменить размеры окна.'),
            alignment=Qt.AlignCenter
        )
        btn = QPushButton(' Change Fixed Sizes ')
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_fixed_main_window_sizes(300, 150))
        self.layout.addWidget(btn)

    # (изменение - ФИКСИРОВАННОГО Размера Основного Окна Приложения)
    def set_fixed_main_window_sizes(self, width, height):
        print(f'width: {width},  height: {height}')  # .....
        self.setWindowFlags(
            Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint |
            Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
        )
        self.setFixedSize(width, height)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Bahnschrift Light", 18))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("** Title ** setFixedSize(500, 200) ")
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Qt.png"))
    # w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я хотел научиться устанавливать размеры Основного Окна приложения - НЕИЗМЕННЫМИ. А потом, если возникнет необходимость, переустанавливать
их и снова делать НЕИЗМЕННЫМИ. Теперь я знаю, как это сделать.
Это делает метод класса Основного Окна приложения - set_fixed_main_window_sizes

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).